# Как создать динамический файл с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с задачей.
Есть файл в котором, например, 5 строк. Пускай это будет`text.txt`. Есть файл `go.php` - из него мы добавляем строку в `text.txt`.

Что сделать, чтобы при добавлении новой строки в `text.txt` удалялась последняя строка из этого же файла, а остальные четыре сдвигались на одну позицию вниз (количество строк остается прежним)?

Желательно пример реализации на `PHP`, если такое возможно
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, свой код. И укажите на моменты, которые по вашему мнению не работают так, как ожидается. Никто здесь целиком за вас код писать не будет.

Comment: @polyvanov вот вам [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a856a594de3376d1b48460077632088a9bdb673c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под этим длинным текстом вы имели в виду *"добавить строку в начало файла, и удалить одну с конца"*, то, вероятно, это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$lines = file("data.txt");
array_unshift($lines, "new line".PHP_EOL);
array_pop($lines);
file_put_contents("data.txt", $lines);
```

для любителей компактного но малочитаемого кода, можно одной строкой

```
file_put_contents("data.txt", array_merge(["new line".PHP_EOL], array_slice( file("data.txt"), 0, 4)));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все заработало

Comment: @polyvanov тогда можете [принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)